# Create APK file of automation script using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, appium

after put appium 'java-client' dependencies in android studio not build .apk what i do please tell me

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        jumboMode = true
        // preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ignatiuz.photoboothapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    // compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
}
```

[and my jar detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y0hO.png)

[and my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdQm9.png)

Error Text

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. 
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/beans/BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey.class

Comment: Could you put the error in the text of your question please, imgur is often blocked, and people don't like having to type things out to look for help for you.

Comment: Added above, please check.... Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/beans/BeanCopier$BeanCopierKey.class

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle to import all the dependencies that you need instead of adding them in `/libs` folder

These are the dependencies I'm having in `build.gradle` for connecting and running Appium tests.

```
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.21.0'
compile 'com.testdroid:testdroid-api:2.9'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.21.0'
```